# Reset @row count on product change

Tags: mysql

I am doing a row count> It works 100% when i only have one products. But when i add a second product i need it to start counting from 1 on every product change.

This works

```
SET @row_num:=0;

SELECT  `product`,
        `market_value_1`,
        `ipdate`,
        (@row_num := @row_num + 1) AS row_num
FROM `ipproject`.`report_combined`
WHERE ipdate BETWEEN '2020-11-01' AND '2021-11-01'
AND product = 'ASISA MA High Equity Composite'
GROUP BY `product` ,`ipdate`
```

This does not

```
SET @row_num:=0;

SELECT  `product`,
        `market_value_1`,
        `ipdate`,
        (@row_num := @row_num + 1) AS row_num
FROM `ipproject`.`report_combined`
WHERE ipdate BETWEEN '2020-11-01' AND '2021-11-01'
AND product = 'ASISA MA High Equity Composite'
OR product = 'ASISA MA Medium Equity Composite'
GROUP BY `product` ,`ipdate`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Wel the @row counts 1005 when only one product is chosen, I need it to start counting from 1 everytime the product changes

p1 1
p1 2
p1 3
p2 1
p2 2

Comment: So it should row count entries for first product, when product name changes it should start counting from one again til product name changes again then start back at 1